# Unable to hide some components from some specific routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

So I have this app which have the same layout in all routes except in two, Login and Register. I have been trying to have a totally separate layout for Login and Register routes but I'm unable to do so.

The `App` component have all the routes and I'm checking with conditionals the value of of the components which I want to hide with the help of `window.location.pathnam`. If the user is in '/' (which is the login route) or '/register', then return empty string. If they are in some other routes, then return those components.

But right now the login/register route doesn't show the components but if I go to an inner route where there were supposed to be header, sidebar, footer components, I don't see them. They disappeared from the routes where they are supposed to be.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the App comp:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import style from './App.module.css';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen/RegisterScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen/LoginScreen';
import Screen3 from './screens/Screen3/Screen3';
import Screen4 from './screens/Screen4/Screen4';
import Screen5 from './screens/Screen5/Screen5';
import Screen6 from './screens/Screen6/Screen6';

const App = () => {

    let header = window.location.pathname === '/' || '/register' ? '' : <Header />;
    let sidebar = window.location.pathname === '/' || '/register' ? '' : <Sidebar />;
    let footer = window.location.pathname === '/' || '/register' ? '' : <Footer />;

    return (
        <Router>
            {/* <Header /> */}
            {header}

            <div className={style.appBody}>

                {/* <Sidebar /> */}
                {sidebar}

                <main className={style.main}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' component={LoginScreen} exact />
                        <Route path='/register' component={RegisterScreen} exact />
                        <Route path='/screen3' component={Screen3} exact />
                        <Route path='/screen4' component={Screen4} exact />
                        <Route path='/screen5' component={Screen5} exact />
                        <Route path='/screen6' component={Screen6} exact />
                    </Switch>
                </main>

            </div>

            {/* <Footer /> */}
            {footer}
        </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `useLocation` from `react-router-dom` to get the current pathname.
2. With the .split() function you're able to get the last item.
3. In the components that change depending on the location (Header, Footer, ...), create your condition (using ternary operator or switch case condition).

Examples :

**Header.js** (with ternary operator)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Header() {
  const path = useLocation().pathname;
  const location = path.split('/')[1];

  return (
    <div>
      {location === 'login' ? (
        <div>
          
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Footer.js** (with switch case condition)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA';
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB';
import ComponentC from './components/ComponentC';

export default function Footer() {
  const path = useLocation().pathname;
  const location = path.split('/')[1];

  const checkLocation = (uri) => {
    switch (uri) {
      case 'login':
        return <ComponentA />;
      case 'register':
        return <ComponentB/>;
      case 'about':
        return <ComponentC />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {checkLocation(location)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Demo:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pwjng1?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 0):

Create two different layout , my suggestion is create src/layouts folder and save here your layouts.  On your app.js or index.js use react router two switch between different layouts

Ps. Basically your sidebar, footer, navbar should be inside of your customize layout not on app.js or index.js